# Can't boot Vista after installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Vista - after Boot-Repair

Tags: dual-boot, windows-vista

Have installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows Vista.
I was able to boot either for a while but now only Ubuntu - if I select Vista from menu it returns to the menu after failing to Boot.
Have tried System Repair on Vista but doesn't correct problem.
There must be a simple solution to this - I really don't want to reinstall Vista from old Recovery Discs.
The guys at Ubuntu can't push this dual use with it failing so easily! Or can they?
Have looked at some related problems but no help to me.

---

I ran Boot-Repair as per forum advice. Rebooted but still can't get Vista.

url was http://paste.ubuntu.com/5962852

(Also sent to boot.repair@gmail.com)

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu). Follow the instructions. After the "Recommended Repair" boot-repair will provide a link(URL). Add this URL in your question (edit the question's description). Although boot-repair might correct the problem at once.

Comment: I really think that Ubuntu might have nothing to do with the problem booting Vista. As you point out, you tried "System Repair" on Vista, that means that the GRUB pass correctly the control to Vista but Vista fails afterwards.

Comment: No problem before Ubuntu installed tho' @Braiam. I grant you Vista is hardly the perfect OS!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use boot-repair, a small but helpful utilty to repair boot problems. It's better to use the recommended settings.

See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

**You can download it in Ubuntu and run it. Hope this helps.**